# Get position of range

Tags: ckeditor

I need to be able to get the coordinates of the caret (as in the blinking cursor line) on the page. The intention is then I am going to overlay a tooltip-like element absolutely positioned to look like a tooltip is appearing below the caret.

I already am getting the range (CKEDITOR.dom.range) from the selection before this runs, and the range is always collapsed, so the method I'm writing needs to get the position for a collapsed range.

This is what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Get the position of a range
 *
 * @param   {CKEDITOR.dom.range}    range   The range (i.e. indicating where the caret is)
 * @returns {void}
 */
this.getRangePosition = function( range ){

    /* Start with wherever we are scrolled to */
    var top = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop)  - (document.documentElement.clientTop || 0);
    var left = (window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft) - (document.documentElement.clientLeft || 0);

    /* Figure out where the containing element (usually the <p>) is and add that's position on */
    var containingElement = range.startContainer.getParent(); // We know range range.startContainer is always text so getParent() takes us to the element 
    var rect = containingElement.getClientRect();
    top += rect.top + rect.height;
    left += rect.left;

    /* And then figure out how far along we are... */

};
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to figure out what to do from there. How I have it now gets the correct value for top but not for left as I'm not sure to figure out how far along the range is from the outside of the element.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this, I ended up doing this:

- Create a snapshot of the editor and a bookmark for the current selection
- Insert an element, then use jQuery's .offset() method on that tp figure out the position
- Restore the snapshot (without that element) and the selection bookmark

  ```
  var snapshot = editor.getSnapshot();
  var bookmarks = editor.getSelection().createBookmarks2( true );
  var fakeElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'span' );
  editor.insertElement( fakeElement );
  var position = $(fakeElement.$).offset();
  editor.loadSnapshot( snapshot );
  editor.focus();
  editor.getSelection().selectBookmarks( bookmarks );
  ```